# Entity Framework performance using different type of access

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been looking into an issue with performance using Entity Framework v6 for the last days and see no way to resolve the issue.

I have an object A (called Company in the examples below) which contains a list of second objects B (Material in the examples below). I now want to grab one piece of A and work with all objects of type B which are contained in A. For this test I am using 10000 pieces of B.

When I receive the object the response time from the server is 5-10 seconds using one type of access, using the second type of access it is using only 0.2 to 0.3 seconds. I am just not able to figure out why.

Fast reaction (~ 0.2 to 0.3s): EXAMPLE1

```
    using (var cont = new Context())
    {
        Company C = cont.Companies.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ID == 18);
        var mat = cont.Materials.Where(o => o.Company.ID == 18);
        foreach (Material m in mat) { } // do stuff, does not matter
    }
```

Slow reaction (~ 5 - 10s): EXAMPLE2

```
    using (var cont = new Context())
    {
        Company C = cont.Companies.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ID == 18);
        var mat = C.materials; // takes forever
        foreach (Material m in mat) { } // do stuff, does not matter
    }
```

There is a second possibility for me to get to slow reaction: EXAMPLE3

```
    using (var cont = new Context())
    {
        cont.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Company C = cont.Companies.Include(o => o.materials).SingleOrDefault(o => o.ID == 18); // takes forever
        var mat = C.materials; // fast
        foreach (Material m in mat) { } // do stuff, does not matter
    }
```

I am just not able to figure out the problem. I have used glimpse to look at the timeline. Problem is: in the first two examples the SQL execution time is only ~100 ms. In Example 2 there is a time-gap between last execution of SQL and end-request of 5 - 10 seconds. In example 3 the SQL statement is completely different (and complex) and actually takes 5 - 10 seconds. The SQL statements for examples 1 and 2 are exactly the same!

Does anybody have an idea what is going on?

These are the definitions of my two classes:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Material> Materials { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
    }
}

public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Producer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public Material()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You sure that example 1 and 2 produce Exactly the same query ? I believe example 1 has additional where. I believe it is faster as You are using Where statement against primary key which is most likely an index - this might cause the speed of example1

Comment: Second example produce more records so most likely it's not sql enginge slow to make this query, it's just more data to send across.

Comment: There are actually two SQL statements for examples 1 and 2: first the Company class is received. After this the materials are received. Both SQL statements are exactly the same for examples 1 and 2 (except for some comments).

Comment: Example 1:
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Company_ID] AS [Company_ID]
    FROM [dbo].[Materials] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 18 = [Extent1].[Company_ID]

Example 2: 
SELECT 
 [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
 [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
 [Extent1].[Company_ID] AS [Company_ID]
 FROM [dbo].[Materials] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE [Extent1].[Company_ID] = 18 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */

Comment: How many records are returned by both Materials query ?

Comment: Checked this: exactly the same (10000)

Comment: In example one you use lazy loading. So, you should see a new query for each iteration in the for each loop. This individual query can be quite fast of course, but are you sure that it is not called 10,000 times? To test this add `ToList()` after `var mat = cont.Materials.Where(o => o.Company.ID == 18)`

Comment: Adding `ToList()` in example 1 will not influence performance (still fast). Examples 1+2 use lazy loading, but there is only one SQL query which is reading all 10000 records as a result at once.

Comment: very interesting, I will try this on some of my own sluggish queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more testing I found a solution to make all queries equally fast. The Material class needs a direct reference to the index of the Company class. I assume access is much faster this way, because the object does not have to be loaded every time?! I still don't understand why the first example was fast with the original classes. Or why the SQL queries look exactly the same in examples 1 and 2 with a significant performance difference.

```
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Producer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; } // THIS IS NEW!!!
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public Material()
    {
    }
}
```